# Ruby on Rails "good/best pactices" sources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

Often I obtain a lot of errors like this:

```
~/.gem/ruby/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:314:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.3. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

Generally, I understand, simply, it is lake of knwoleadge of good practices to build ROR applications generally and, particulary how to build Gemfile.

Is there anybody who can recomment online sources to improve skills?

Comment: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide - https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Incidentally, this question is inspecific. It's not entirely clear if you are asking about fixing dependencies in the Gemfile or talking about the world of working with Rails in general. If it's a general "help me be a better programmer" question, it's not really the right place to be asking about it.

Comment: Ok.  This problem I must solve by myself. Thank you. "To be a better programmer" - in memories.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't go to the heart of the error or errors, but the two style guides are good if you're looking to write better code:

rails: https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide
ruby: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 0):

small addition to above comments - rubocop gem ( https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop ) is a nice command line utility which helps in keeping ruby code clean (it uses different kind of checks based on ruby & rails guidelines mentioned above).